# only 1 record is being inserted

Tags: .net, oledb

I'm running an insert statement using OLE DB and an ICommandWithParameters.

In the ICommandText, I made sure to set:

```
params.cParamSets = n ;
```

Then

```
cmdTxt->Execute( NULL, IID_NULL, ¶ms, &rowsAffected, NULL ) ;
```

Where n > 1, but in my database, all I see is 1 insert happening.

The docs say [cParamSets is greater than one) can be specified only if DBPROP_MULTIPLEPARAMSETS is VARIANT_TRUE and the command does not return any rowsets.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718095(VS.85).aspx)

But I set DBPROP_MULTIPLEPARAMSETS in my DBPROPs, and its and INSERT statement so it should not return any rowsets.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a MySQL database underneath, and I tried the same exact insert with SQL Server and the multiple insert with prepared statement worked.

It SEEMS this is a MySQL problem.